# How to implement a decreasing life system in Javascript and canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement a decreasing life system in a basic frogger style Javascript game. I had a counter system work in which lives were displayed numerically, counting down from 3 to 0 when the player character hits an enemy.

Now, I'm trying to replace the numeric countdown with displayed unicode hearts. Ideally, there would be three hearts at game launch, and each collision would decrease the displayed hearts by 1.

With my code, this works if I display the lives as an array, but it shows the commas separating the hearts. If I try to display it as a string, the commas are gone but the hearts no longer decrease. I feel like I'm so close, but I'm stumped.

Thanks!

```
var playerLives = ['&#128154;', '&#128154;', '&#128154;'];
var hearts = playerLives.join(' ');
//turn playerLives array into hearts string

var playerScore = 0;
var scoreEl = document.getElementById('score');

function checkCollisions() {
    for (var i = 0; i < allEnemies.length; i++) {
        if (player.x <= allEnemies[i].x + 70
            && player.x + 70 >= allEnemies[i].x
            && player.y <= allEnemies[i].y + 50
            && player.y + 50 >= allEnemies[i].y)
        {
                player.x = 200;
                player.y = 415;
                hearts.slice(-10);
                //attempt to remove string from hearts, but doesn't
                //work
                playerLives.splice(-1, 1);
                //decrease playerLives array by 1 on collision
                if (playerScore >= 50) {
                    playerScore -= 50;
                    scoreEl.textContent = 'Score: ' + playerScore;
                }
                //reset(); //create reset function
        }
    }
}

function score() {
    if (player.y < 60) {
        player.x = 200;
        player.y = 415;
        playerScore += 100;
        scoreEl.textContent = 'Score: ' + playerScore;
        level++;
        levelEl.textContent = 'Level: ' + level;
    }
}

function playerLife() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var lifeEl = document.getElementById('life');
        lifeEl.innerHTML = 'Lives: ' + hearts; // lives appear as 
        //string and do not decrease on collision
        //if use "'Lives: ' + playerLives" hearts do decrease 
        //but appear as an array with commas separating
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `.splice()` on the `playerLives` array, but you display the `hearts` string.

Comment: I do, thank you. But if I display the `playerLives` array instead, it shows the hearts separated by commas. Is there a way to show `playerLives` without commas, or `hearts` and have it decrease on collision?

Answer (score 1):

To convert array to string without delimiters use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with empty string :

```
playerLives.join("");
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. `lifeEl.innerHTML = 'Lives: ' + playerLives.join("");` works like a charm